# Is it possible to assign a static ip to a website hosted on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I already have reserved a static ip with google cloud. But before I switch from a VM to Firebase to host my website, I want to know if I can use my static ip with Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Firebase products that accept distinct IPs for configuration.  They are all cloud-hosted services with their own dedicated DNS and IPs that must be used as-is.

Firebase Hosting allows you to [set up an A record for you custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) to point to its provided IP address.